# Attach a Segmented Control to UINavigationBar

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar, uisegmentedcontrol

In my App, I have a map view and I want to use a segmented control to change the map types (Standard, Hybrid, Satellite). The way I have the app set up, the status bar is hidden and it animates in, moving the navigation bar down a bit. To make sure it doesn't look awkward, I want to make it so the segmented control is attached to the navigation bar so it animates nicely as the status bar comes in. This is basically a picture of what I want to do:
[image]

So I noticed that the segmented control is inside a toolbar, so I contain mine in a toolbar as well. I've then tried adding the toolbar to the navigationBar as a subview. (`self.navigationController.navigationBar`). That works well accept that it can't be tapped because the navigation bar's frame doesn't enclose the extra space, so it can't receive touches. I tried making the frame of the bar bigger, and that worked, but the title and the buttons went away. Obviously there is some way to do this, and I would appreciate any help. Thanks.

Comment: Add a toolbar, and pin it to the `topLayoutGuide`.